# Start animate UIView before complete?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I'm using `[UIView animateWithDuration:...]` for animate sequence of `UIImageView` views. Like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    imageView.frame = newImageRectPosition;
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
 //animate next UIImageView
}];
```

I need animate 'next UIImageView' not on completion. I need animate 'next UIImageView' on the middle of previous animation, not on completion. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Start another animation with a delay of 0.5s

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609589/870028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup two UIView animation blocks, one which has a delay of half the duration of the first animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                 animations:^{ ... }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ ... }
];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.5
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{ ... }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) { ... }
];
```

Comment: This way works, however, I would argue that using animateKeyframesWithDuration is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options you can use to achieve the effect you're after. One which comes to mind is the use of timers.

Use an NSTimer with a firing interval half of that of your animation, and get the timer to fire off another animation. As long as the two animations don't interfere with each other, you should be ok.

An example would be as so:

```
NSTimer* timer;
// Modify to your uses if so required (i.e. repeating, more than 2 animations etc...)
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:animationTime/2 target:self selector:@selector(runAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationTime animations:^{
    imageView.frame = newImageRectPosition;
} completion:nil];

- (void)runAnimation
{ 
    // 2nd animation required
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationTime animations:^{
        imageView.frame = newImageRectPosition;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

With a timer, this could scale up if you needed to do more than two animations, and it all holds together if you need to change the animation time later on.

Comment: Using an NSTimer for an animation block which accepts a `delay` seems a bit dumb. Just use the view animation with a delay...

Comment: Depends on the situation; say you have n animations that you need to run. By specifying the animation with delay, you have to commit them all at the same time, which with a large number of n might be a logistical nightmare depending on animation times and their respective delays. 

With Timers, you get it to commit the animation when needed. Getting the timer to repeat at regular intervals to commit an animation block makes management of times and delays easier.

I concur though, that in this situation, with only 2 animation blocks, the delay will be the easiest and the most appropriate.

Comment: And I concur with the example you gave :)