# Animate multiple views where one starts before another finishes

Tags: ios, animation

I'd like to animate several views, which are essentially squares that get bigger then go back to original size. The number of views can vary and are animated in sequential order, where one view animation starts just before its preceding view completes. I tried the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    SView *view = _row[i];

    view.widthConstraint.constant *= 1.1;
    view.heightConstraint.constant *= 1.1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:1 * i
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                       [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       view.widthConstraint.constant /= 1.1;
                       view.heightConstraint.constant /= 1.1;

                       [UIView animateWithDuration:.1
                                             delay:0
                                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                        animations:^{
                                          [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                        }];
                     }];
  }
}
```

This ends up being very choppy and "blinking", if that makes sense, and nothing like what I was expecting. Any idea how to accomplish this sequential animation and still make it very smooth?

Comment: What do you mean by choppy and blinking? Could you show a video of what is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a video but the entire set of views (they all have images on them) becomes white, then a few appear, followed by more after ~1 second, then the rest another ~1 sec. The scaling animations don't happen, the views simply appear in the final size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **right** way to do this is by using keyframes. It makes for much cleaner code. The UIView methods to use are these:

> animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
> addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:

## Simple Example

Here is a simple example on how to use it:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.25
                               delay:0
                             options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                          animations:^{
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.7 animations:^{
                                  avatarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
                              }];
                              [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.7 relativeDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                                  avatarView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                              }];
                          } completion:nil];
```

The idea is that you define an overall duration then break up how much each individual animation takes and is delayed in relation to the overall animation.

## Looping Example

If you have multiple views that need to be keyframed, you can actually have a loop within the animation block. This allows for flexible and dynamic code. Here is an [example project](https://github.com/JohnnySlagle/LoopingKeyframeAnimation) and some code:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0
                               delay:0
                             options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                          animations:^{
                              for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:(duration / numberOfViews) animations:^{
                                      ... animate view ...
                                  }];
                              }
                          } completion:nil];
```

Comment: I'd use keyframes if the number of views were constant, but the number varies depending on user selection.

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes sense. I just typed this but haven't tried it yet. What if you put a for-loop inside the animation block? Then you could loop through and add animations? I don't know if that works but it might be worth a shot?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on for-loop inside animation block. It's creating the effect I was looking for.

Comment: @user1192805 No problem. I've updated the answer and attached an example project.

Comment: This is perfect for custom animators (UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to animate is by using 
`animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` and 
`addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:`
 . Just look up how to use that API.

I feel that you'll find that it ends up being much cleaner and clearer.